# How to connect Amazon API Gateway with my custom API in EC2

Tags: api, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to create a RESTful API to expose a Windows application as a service. My first step is to create a simple REST API that returns a string, and then connect it to Amazon API Gateway.

I already launched a Windows Server instance, installed Node.js and created a simple API like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
       console.log( "response" );
       res.end( "response" );
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

I'd tested it opening `http://localhost:8080/test` and it works perfect.

The thing is, now I have to connect it with Amazon API Gateway but I haven't found clear documentation of how to do that. I have to use the "HTTP Proxy" option (see image below) but how do I get an "Endpoint URL"? All the tutorials take for granted that I already have that URL, but I don't.

[image]

Comment: Does this works when you change localhost here http://localhost:8080/test with http://<public-ip-of-your-EC2-instance>:8080/test

Comment: I'm getting a timeout in that case. The port is already opened.

Comment: Is you instance in a Private Subnet?

Comment: How do I know if the subnet is private?

Comment: Run this command on you EC2 and let me know what output you get  wget http ://www.google.com there is a space after http remove that when you paste it in your EC2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to the ec2 console
2. Look for your instance
3. In the [description of the instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8qsd.png) find its public ip
4. Make sure its security group has the right permissions other wise you will no be able to connect with it
5. Use the instance public ip in API Gateway

In production use a more robust configuration, but for testing purposes you should be good.